# Grouping floating point numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point

I have an application where I need to block average a list of data (currently in a `pandas.DataFrame`) according to a timestamp, which may be a floating point value. For example, I may need to average the following `df` into groups of `0.3` secs:

```
+------+------+         +------+------+
| secs |  A   |         | secs |  A   |
+------+------+         +------+------+
| 0.1  |  ..  |         | 0.3  |  ..  | <-- avg of 0.1, 0.2, 0.3
| 0.2  |  ..  |   -->   | 0.6  |  ..  | <-- avg of 0.4, 0.5, 0.6
| 0.3  |  ..  |         | ...  | ...  | <-- etc
| 0.4  |  ..  |         +------+------+
| 0.5  |  ..  |
| 0.6  |  ..  |
| ...  | ...  |
+------+------+
```

Currently I am using the following (minimal) solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def block_avg ( df : pd.DataFrame, duration : float ) -> pd.DataFrame:
    grouping = (df['secs'] - df['secs'][0]) // duration
    df = df.groupby( grouping, as_index=False ).mean()
    df['secs'] = duration * np.arange(1,1+len(df))
    return df
```

which works just fine for integer `duration`s, but floating point values at the edges of blocks can fall on the wrong side. A simple test that the blocks are being created properly is to average by the same `duration` that the data is already in (`0.1` in this example). This should return the input, but often doesn't. (e.g. `x=.1*np.arange(1,20); (x-x[0])//.1)`.)

I found that the error with this method is usually that the LSB is 1 low, so a tentative fix is to add `np.spacing(df['secs'])` to the numerator in the `grouping`. (That is, `x=.1*np.arange(1,20); all( (x-x[0]+np.spacing(x)) // .1 == np.arange(19) )` returns `True`.)

However, I am concerned that this is not a robust solution. Is there a better or preferred way to group floats which passes the above test?

I have had similar issues with a (perhaps more straightforward) algorithm which groups using `x[ (duration*i < x) & (x <= duration*(i+1)) ]` and looping `i` over an appropriate range.

Comment: The main issue is that floating points are always going to be inaccurate, can you use ms or ns (i.e. `np.timedelta`)?

Comment: @AndyHayden Unfortunately I don't have much control of how the data is written. But (for now) it will always be in integer multiples of 1 ms, so I can `((...)*1000).astype(int)` if I have to. Being aware that float is (almost) always inexact, can there really be no guarantee by padding with `np.spacing` in one (or both) directions?

Comment: right, it's the inexact thing that will bite you, I guess you could round it first?

Comment: At the risk of misusing the comment section, floats are only ever going to be off from the exact intended value by 1 in the LSB (before manipulation I mean). The issue is that I'm not sure how `//` is done on floats, so I can't bound the error. If it turns out the error bound is, say, 5 bits, padding with `5*np.spacing(...)` should be fine, right?

Comment: I think np.round will help normalize to int (and avoid the error),, added an answer to suggest that (among other things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be extra careful (of float inaccuracy) I'd round early before doing the groupby:

```
In [11]: np.round(300 + df.secs * 1000).astype(int) // 300
Out[11]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: secs, dtype: int64

In [12]: (np.round(300 + df.secs * 1000).astype(int) // 300) * 0.3
Out[12]:
0    0.3
1    0.3
2    0.3
3    0.6
4    0.6
5    0.6
Name: secs, dtype: float64

In [13]: df.groupby(by=(np.round(300 + df.secs * 1000).astype(int) // 300) * 0.3)["A"].sum()
Out[13]:
secs
0.3    1.753843
0.6    2.687098
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

I would prefer to use a timedelta:

```
In [21]: s = pd.to_timedelta(np.round(df["secs"], 1), unit="S")

In [22]: df["secs"] = pd.to_timedelta(np.round(df["secs"], 1), unit="S")

In [23]: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="secs", freq="0.3S")).sum()
Out[23]:
                        A
secs
00:00:00         1.753843
00:00:00.300000  2.687098
```

or with a `resample`:

```
In [24]: res = df.set_index("secs").resample("300ms").sum()

In [25]: res
Out[25]:
                        A
secs
00:00:00         1.753843
00:00:00.300000  2.687098
```

you can set the index to correct the labelling*

```
In [26]: res.index += np.timedelta64(300, "ms")

In [27]: res
Out[27]:
                        A
secs
00:00:00.300000  1.753843
00:00:00.600000  2.687098
```

** There ought to be a way to set that through a resample argument, but they don't seem to work...*

Comment: This looks great, I think I agree conversion to ms is best. TBH, I'd never heard of `timedelta` before, but looks like a really nice tool.

Comment: @nivk please consider "accepting" if it works for you :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I generally don't like accepting so soon (especially on low-view questions), but I think I can make an exception. (What, 126k isn't enough for you? ;)